# Algorithm to rank products using ratings and ratings-count

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce, recommendation-engine

What is a proper algorithm/approach to rank these products for recommendation purposes:

- Product-1: 1 rating (5.0 average rating)
- Product-2: 30 ratings (4.9 average rating)
- Product-3: 500 ratings (4.7 average rating)
- etc.

Intuitively, I'd rank product-2 better than product-1, because 30 ratings are considerably more "reliable" than 1 rating despite having slightly lower average score.

The best I could come up with was to normalize the two figures: rating and rating-count, and assign (an arbitrary, really) weight to each, and average them to get a crude "ranking" or a recommendation-score. But I keep thinking that would be oversimplifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used solution is to build a *confidence interval* around the average rating. Then, instead of ranking products by their average rating, you can rank them by their lower confidence bound.

For instance:

- Product-1: 1 rating, 5.0 average rating, `[4.0,6.0]` confidence interval, 4.0 lowerbound
- Product-2: 30 ratings, 4.9 average rating, `[4.8,5.0]` confidence interval, 4.8 lowerbound
- Product-3: 500 ratings, 4.7 average rating, `[4.65,4.75]` confidence interval, 4.6 lowerbound

Ranking by lowerbound gives: first Product-2, then Product-3, then Product-1.

Related: [Wilson's confidence interval for 5-star rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613023/wilsons-confidence-interval-for-5-star-rating).

Keywords when searching for algorithms using confidence in ratings:

- [TrueSkill](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/trueskill-ranking-system/) rating system
- Wilson score
- [ELO rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)
- [Sonas rating](https://en.chessbase.com/post/the-sonas-rating-formula-better-than-elo)